# Why does "to have a prayer" refer to chance?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> 1) With an injured ankle, he **doesn't have a prayer** of winning the race.
>
> 2) [from *Seinfeld*, "The Boyfriend"]
>
> -- Sometimes I've given my number out to guys and it takes them a month to call.
>
> -- Ha!  If he's calling in a month, **he's got a prayer**!

Why does "to have a prayer" mean "to have a chance"? As I see it, if someone is *praying* for you, you have more chances to succeed (in the religious sense) because God *is being asked* for it. And if nobody is praying (asking God) for you, there is less chance.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard it used positively, as in "he has a prayer of X". As far as I know, it's only ever used when you _don't_ have a prayer.

Comment: I agree with jimsug: in my speech, this is a **negative polarity item**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like how this [one website](http://www.englishdaily626.com/slang.php?059) explains the idiom:

> When something is very difficult, you might 'pray' for assistance. If something 'has a prayer', it might succeed if it gets a little bit of assistance from above. But if it 'doesn't have a prayer', not even divine intervention will help.

A similar (in meaning) idiom is "an ice cube's chance," which is a shortened form of "an ice cube's chance in hell," referring to the chance that an ice cube could withstand the fires of hell.

> With an injured ankle, he doesn't have an *ice cube's chance* of winning the race.

Comment: So, when Jerry said the second line (my second example) he was being sarcastic? It is like someone says "Can I get into Harvard with 950 on the SAT?" and gets an answer "Yeah, you've got a good chance!"

Comment: I'd have to see the whole scene in the episode to know for sure. Has a prayer for what? Becoming her boyfriend? I can't really be sure from the context. As for getting into Harvard with a 950, I could say, "No, you don't have a prayer," or, if I wanted to be sarcastic, I might say, "Well, if it's a down year for applications, then maybe you have a prayer!" (all the while knowing that no year is a "down year" at Harvard). Yet another interesting way it's said with sarcasm from time to time is "half a prayer": _Do the Pacers have half a prayer to get this Series to a Game 7? I don't think so._

Answer (score 1):

I believe "To not have a prayer" comes from a old tradition still in place in Westminster Palace. Members of the Parliament have to come in early and reserve their seat for sessions later in the day. Their name is written on a little note that goes on the back the seat. Most people don't attend the actual prayer that the original seats were meant for of course.
Consequently however, "if you haven't got a prayer" (as the mp:s call these reserved seats) you haven't got a chance of a decent seat later on.

Comment: Welcome to the site! you are stating an interesting point, could you perhaps add some link or add your source?

Answer (score 0):

> With an injured ankle, he **doesn't have a prayer** of winning the race.

is essentially the same as

> With an injured ankle, he **doesn't have a chance** of winning the race.

However while you could say

> Because he got lots of rest, he **has a chance** of winning the race.

I have never heard a phrase like

> Because he got lots of rest, he **has a prayer** of winning the race.

I may be wrong, but I would say *doesn't have a prayer* is idiomatic and only works in the negative. But it could be like you were abandoned because nobody prayed for you.

Comment: You explained how to use it, but you didn't explain why it means that.

Answer (score 0):

The expression **doesn't have a prayer** means **doesn't *even* have *so much as* a prayer**.

The idea is that some things are so far-fetched, they would take divine intervention to come about, but other things are even less likely than that, and for them not even divine intervention would do it.

The idiom is in the negative ***doesn't* have a prayer**; the positive formation, **has a prayer** is an allusion to it, and in contrast to it.  Your second example

> If he's calling in a month, he's got a prayer!

Means, *He wouldn't even have a prayer of a chance, were it not for that he's called in a month; his having called in a month upgrades his odds from flatly impossible to only requiring an Act of God.*

Answer (score 0):

*get a prayer* or *have a prayer* means **have a chance or hope**. I'm not sure *why* is it so because this usage is *slang*. The *slang* words are fun to learn. We just accept them and enjoy the usage.

Collins describes it.

> [prayer (n)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/prayer?showCookiePolicy=true) - *a chance or hope*

Again, note that it's described as slang. It is for this reason, it sounds a bit different and not natural.

Knowing this meaning, I hope both the sentences are clear now.